# Assistance with SQL Server SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just started to learn SQL and would be very thankful if you can help with SELECT query. There are input variables: `@p_IPN` and `@p_SecondName`, the table has `SECONDNAME`, `FIRSTNAME`, `MIDDLENAME` and `IPN` columns.

I need to perform search in my table by the specified input characters with the following conditions:

- if none of variables is specified, the query should return the entire table;
- if `@p_IPN` OR `@p_SecondName` is specified, the query should perform search by `IPN LIKE @p_IPN OR SECONDNAME LIKE @p_SecondName`;
- if both variables are specified, the query should return rows with input characters of `@p_IPN` AND `@p_SecondName` (`IPN LIKE @p_IPN AND SECONDNAME LIKE @p_SecondName`)

I used the following query:

```
IF (@p_IPN IS NULL AND @p_SecondName IS NULL)
    SELECT 
        CAST(IPN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, MIDDLENAME 
    FROM
        dbo.BE_BlackList
ELSE IF (@p_IPN IS NULL)
    SELECT 
        CAST(IPN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, MIDDLENAME    
    FROM
        dbo.BE_BlackList
    WHERE 
        SECONDNAME LIKE @p_SecondName
ELSE IF (@p_SecondName IS NULL)
    SELECT 
        CAST(IPN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, MIDDLENAME    
    FROM
        dbo.BE_BlackList
    WHERE 
        IPN LIKE @p_IPN
ELSE
    SELECT 
        CAST(IPN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, MIDDLENAME    
    FROM
        dbo.BE_BlackList
    WHERE 
        IPN LIKE @p_IPN AND SECONDNAME LIKE @p_SecondName
```

It works well, still, I need to have the same result using SELECT query.

I tried this:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN @p_IPN IS NULL AND @p_Secondname IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT cast (IPN AS nvarchar(max)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, SECONDNAME FROM dbo.BE_BlackList)

               WHEN @p_SecondName IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT cast(IPN AS nvarchar(max)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, SECONDNAME FROM dbo.BE_BlackList
             WHERE IPN LIKE @p_IPN)

               WHEN @p_IPN IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT cast(IPN AS nvarchar(max)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, SECONDNAME FROM dbo.BE_BlackList
             WHERE SECONDNAME LIKE @p_Secondname)

         ELSE 
            (SELECT cast (IPN AS nvarchar(max)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, SECONDNAME FROM dbo.BE_BlackList
             WHERE SECONDNAME LIKE @p_Secondname AND IPN LIKE @p_IPN)
         END
FROM dbo.BE_BlackList
```

I get this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I am not sure how to use `CASE WHEN EXISTS` here (if possible at all). Could you help, please?

Comment: Sounds like a Catch-all query. I suggest having a read up on these: [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/), followed by [Revisiting Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

Comment: Hi Lina, You are thinking of SQL like other 3 GL Languages (e.g. Java, C#, etc.). It is a 4 GL language and is used differently.

Comment: Thank @Larnu ,  
the article is helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using IF ELSE, you could use WHERE for your condition filter

```
SELECT 
    CAST(IPN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS IPN, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, MIDDLENAME 
FROM
    dbo.BE_BlackList
WHERE 
   (@p_IPN IS NULL OR IPN LIKE @p_IPN)
   AND
   (@p_SecondName IS NULL OR SECONDNAME LIKE @p_SecondName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `CASE WHEN` syntax. Think of `CASE WHEN` as a column. In other words, `SELECT CASE WHEN a = b, THEN c FROM dbo.BE_BlackList`

You are saying `SELECT CASE WHEN a = b then SELECT c from dbo.BE_Blacklist` - Notice there are two select statements here.